# Cooling tea: average temperature from derivative

Tags: integration

I couldn't get the correct answer for this question:

> A science geek brews tea at $195 \:\rm °F$ and observes that the temperature $T(t) \:\rm °F$ of the tea after $t$ minutes is changing at the rate of $$T’(t)=-6.5e^{-0.05t}$$
>   What is the average temperature of the tea during the first $13$ minutes after being brewed?

What I first did is to take the integral of $T’$ with the upper bound $13$ and lower bound $0$ and found the value as $-62.13$. Since it says the average, I divided the answer by $13$ and added it to $195$. Can someone find my mistake?

Comment: The average value of the actual temperature is $\frac{1}{13} \int_0^{13} T(t) dt$, not $\frac{1}{13} \int_0^{13} T'(t) dt$.

Comment: ...and $\frac{1}{13} \int_0^{13} T'(t) dt$ is the average rate of change over the time interval.

Comment: coffee or tea??

Comment: Does that mean that I have to take the integral twice?

Answer (score 1):

$T(t) = \int T'(t) dt =  \int (-6.5 e^{-0.05t}) dt = 130 e^{-0.05t} + C$

Since $T(0)=195, C=65$.

Averaged temperature, t=0 to 13 minutes:

$$ \frac{1}{13} \int_0^{13} (130 e^{-0.05t} + 65)dt =\frac{1}{13} [-2600 e^{-0.05t} + 65t ] _0 ^{13} ≈ 160.59 °F $$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature at any time is $T(t)=195+\int_0^tT'(\tau) d\tau$.  I didn't check, but your integration should say that the final temperature is $195-62.13$.  A first cut at the average would then be $\frac 12(195+(195-62.13))$.  Dividing by $13$ is clearly wrong, because the final result should not have a unit of time in the denominator.  The first cut assumes that the temperature decrease is linear, which is not correct.  The correct average would be $\frac 1{13}\int_0^{13}T(t)dt$.  The integral supplies a unit of time which is divided out by the $13$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that I have to take another integral of the integral I found? In that case, how am I going to solve the +C?

Comment: My integral is a definite one, so there is no $+C$.  Your result ignored the $195$ starting temperature

Answer (score 0):

The temperature decreases according to

$$T(t)-195=\int_0^t T’(s)ds$$

So, it varies as a function of time $t$ as,

$$T(t)=195- 6.5\int_0^t e^{-0.05s}ds=65+ 130e^{-0.05t}$$

The average temperature is then

$$T_a=\frac{1}{13}\int_0^{13} T(t)dt$$

$$T_a=\frac{1}{13}\int_0^{13} (65+130e^{-0.05t})dt=65+200(1-e^{-0.65})=160.6F$$